# Why won't the font-size change?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-size

I'm trying to change the font-size inside a menu. When I adjust the font-size it only changes the space between the letters for some reason. Any ideas?

```
#mainNav ul li {
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 100px; 
    font: "Tahoma";
    letter-spacing: .02em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

Comment: Working fine for me. Are you sure you were changing the font-size and not the letter-spacing? http://jsfiddle.net/eW6XY/

Comment: Please post a complete code example so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Other CSS might be overriding your font-size. It's impossible to debug without following the proper SO protocol (example of all relevant and accompanying code). We need the HTML and accompanying CSS for the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can have some css overriding on the font-size, you can confirm the styles using the inspect of your browser. 
To solve this you can also try to change the priority of the styles buy adding the !important.

```
 font-size: 100px !important;
```

But if you still having the same issue you must use the inspect to correct the priority of the styles.

Answer (score 0):

if is a menu, you must have an "a" in the "li" and the font-size for this with any value.